# Preselect files in JUpload

Tags: java, file-upload, applet, jupload

I have a requirement to process an external request to populate a `HTML` form with the parameters mentioned in the URL. This part is working fine. However, the URL also contains paths to files present on the client machine and I want to upload those files from the client machine to the server without user interaction.

Since it is not possible with `HTML/Javascript` to programatically select files, I tried using the Applet approach using [JUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/). However, I am not able to figure out, how to preselect a file on applet initialization. It is not necessary to upload the files right away, but **I want atleast to select the files automatically**. User can review the info and then submit the form. and files in the applet.

Is it possible with this library? Or direct me to some better path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found my answer in a different library with similar name. With [Smartwerkz JUpload](http://jupload.biz/) we can pass a parameter `preselectedFiles="filePath"` and `autostartUpload=true` to preselect files and auto upload files without user interaction. I hope it will help someone someday.